# Swift: convert a 2's complement number in String form into an Double

Tags: swift2

I have a sensor which is generating 16 bit values in 2's complement in a string form. I need to do some maths with these value so ultimately I need to convert the to Doubles. Where "f112" is 2's complement example value which will generates -3822.

I am very much a Swift beginner and feel there must be an easier way?

```
let value2 = UInt32("f112",radix:16)
if value2 > 32767 {
    // handle -ve values
    value5 = Int32(bitPattern:value2! | 0xFFFF0000)
} else {
    // +ve
    value5 = Int32(bitPattern:value2! )
}
let doubleValue = Double(value5)
```

Comment: Do you mean `0x0...0x7fff` =  `0...32767` and `0x8000...0xffff` = `-32768...-1` aka the `Int16` range?

Comment: Yes that's it 2's complement representation.

Answer (score 3):

There are probably several solutions, this is one.

First it creates the `UInt16` value and converts it to `Int` to be able to do 32 bit math.

Then it subtracts 0x10000 (65536) if the most significant bit is set.

```
let value2 = Int(UInt16("f112",radix:16)!)
let doubleValue = value2 > 0x7fff ?  Double(value2 - 0x10000) : Double(value2)
```

or using the bitwise NOT operator (`~`)

```
let value2 = UInt16("f112",radix:16)!
let doubleValue = value2 > 0x7fff ? -Double(~value2 + 1) : Double(value2)
```

Comment: Many thanks, your solution is much cleaner & I haven't managed to break it yet :O)

Comment: @vadian, please, do you have an explanation why Int16("f112", radix: 16) returns nil ? For me it looks like a bug ... I expected valid Int16? result

Comment: Because a hexadecimal number is unsigned by default.

Answer (score 1):

my solution is a little bit different from vadian's

```
let str = "f112"
// if you are sure about str (so force unwrapping is fine)
let d = Double(Int16(bitPattern: UInt16(str, radix: 16)!)) // -3822

// or more 'safe' version, which return 0 in case of invalid parameter
let d0 = Double(Int16(bitPattern: UInt16(str, radix: 16) ?? 0)) // -3822
```

by the way

```
Int16("f112", radix: 16) == nil // true!
```

looks like a bug for me ...